# Migrating from JDK 1.5.0_06 to 1.8.0_66 - Replacing the deprecated Java JPEG classes

Tags: java, java-8, jpeg, javax.imageio

I am currently migrating an application from JDK 1.5.0_06 to 1.8.0_66. In the application, there are multiple files that use com.sun.image.codec.jpeg classes. When I try to create a JAR I'm getting the below error.

```
error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.*;
```

I referred the blog on [Replacing the deprecated Java JPEG classes for Java 7](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2012/05/replacing-the-deprecated-java-jpeg-classes-for-java-7/#comment-185733) and my errors were cleared. But now I'm getting the warning below:

```
warning: JPEGImageWriter is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release import com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageWriter;
```

The problematic code from the blog:

```
public static void saveAsJPEG(String jpgFlag, BufferedImage image_to_save, float JPEGcompression, FileOutputStream fos) throws IOException {
    // Image writer
    JPEGImageWriter imageWriter = (JPEGImageWriter) ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpeg").next();
    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(fos);
    imageWriter.setOutput(ios);

    //and metadata
    IIOMetadata imageMetaData = imageWriter.getDefaultImageMetadata(new ImageTypeSpecifier(image_to_save), null);

    if (jpgFlag != null) {
        int dpi = 96;

        try {
            dpi = Integer.parseInt(jpgFlag);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //new metadata
        Element tree = (Element) imageMetaData.getAsTree("javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0");
        Element jfif = (Element) tree.getElementsByTagName("app0JFIF").item(0);
        jfif.setAttribute("Xdensity", Integer.toString(dpi));
        jfif.setAttribute("Ydensity", Integer.toString(dpi));
    }

    if (JPEGcompression >= 0 && JPEGcompression <= 1f) {
        // new Compression
        JPEGImageWriteParam jpegParams = (JPEGImageWriteParam) imageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
        jpegParams.setCompressionMode(JPEGImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        jpegParams.setCompressionQuality(JPEGcompression);
    }

    //new Write and clean up
    imageWriter.write(imageMetaData, new IIOImage(image_to_save, null, null), null);
    ios.close();
    imageWriter.dispose();
}
```

Comment: You are getting a warning because you should not be using internal API - but it's only a warning and you can compile and run your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problematic line in your code is:

```
JPEGImageWriter imageWriter = (JPEGImageWriter) ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpeg").next();
```

There's simply no need for this cast and usage of a specific subclass (`JPEGImageWriter`). It's also a good practice to not rely on specific plugin subclasses. In this case, just use the `ImageWriter` base class.

```
ImageWriter imageWriter = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpeg").next();
```

Everything else will work and run as before.

Note: The `JPEGImageWriteParam` class on the other hand, *is part of the public API* (`javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg` package) and is needed to access JPEG specific writing options. This usage is completely ok.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You made it so easy for me to modify.